# Reading iTunes XML File With PHP

Tags: php, xml, itunes

I'm trying to read the iTunes XML file with PHP. I want to extract particular bits of information. Such as the Name, Artist and Album. How would I do this? I found [this](http://thousandrobots.com/files/itunes.phps) which works quite well when parsing the whole file. I thought perhaps using this to create a whole new XML file which is easier to read.

But there must be a better way.

The XML structure for a track looks like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>Track ID</key><integer>6136</integer>
    <key>Name</key><string>The Boy Who Destroyed the World</string>
    <key>Artist</key><string>AFI</string>
    <key>Album Artist</key><string>AFI</string>
    <key>Composer</key><string>AFI</string>
    <key>Album</key><string>Tony Hawk Pro Skater 3</string>
    <key>Genre</key><string>Punk Rock</string>
    <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
    <key>Size</key><integer>2971924</integer>
    <key>Total Time</key><integer>185364</integer>
    <key>Track Number</key><integer>3</integer>
    <key>Year</key><integer>1999</integer>
    <key>Date Modified</key><date>2009-08-20T15:03:20Z</date>
    <key>Date Added</key><date>2009-08-20T15:03:20Z</date>
    <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>128</integer>
    <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
    <key>Play Count</key><integer>34</integer>
    <key>Play Date</key><integer>3332385360</integer>
    <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2009-08-06T05:36:00Z</date>
    <key>Sort Name</key><string>Boy Who Destroyed the World</string>
    <key>Persistent ID</key><string>9E590180768D4AD8</string>
    <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
    <key>Location</key><string>FilePath</string>
    <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>4</integer>
    <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think parsing the file and then creating another file which is easier to parse is the right solution.  You'll have already parsed the main file, so why make more work?

[simplexml](http://php.net/simplexml) allows you to navigate an XML object with relative ease, so you should be able to get the information you want.  I would use`simplexml_load_file()` or `simplexml_load_string()` to load the main file, and then probably [SimpleXMLElement::xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-xpath.php) to navigate through your resulting XML structure to find the data you want.

Comment: I can't do it with Simple XML. When I parse a track node with it, it comes out like this. http://pastebin.com/f19eca19c

Comment: Whats wrong with the output Ben? Looks like you have an object, then just use that object to output what you need, or inset into a DB of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML is the builtin way to do this. http://www.devshed.com/c/a/XML/SimpleXML/ seems like a good tutorial, as well as the php.net section on simpleXML.